# Copied array acting as original

Tags: ruby

I'm currently working inside a method which is inside a class.

I tried duplicating my array like so:

```
fakearray = []
@puzzarray.each_index do |row|
    fakearray << @puzzarray[row]
end
```

And

```
fakearray = @puzzarray.clone
```

but when I print `@puzzarray` out, I noticed that it keeps all the changes I did for the `fakearray`. The purpose for the `fakearray` was to use it as a clone to check if my code worked before running it on `@puzzarray` but it kept all the bad changes anyway. Any suggestions?

Comment: You should just be able to `dup` an array. `fakearray = @puzzarray.dup`. You can check their `object_id`, `fakearray.object_id == @puzzarray.object_id`, to see they are different objects, if so they are in different memory space and will have no interaction.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this documentation for `dup` as an alternative to your choice of `clone`: [dup](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Object.html#method-i-dup). Within that section in the link is a description of the difference between `clone` and `dup`. Check it out and see if this helps your situation.

Answer (score 0):

Using `activesupport` gem you could use `#deep_dup`:

```
a = ['asd']
deep_copy = a.deep_dup
deep_copy[0] << 'dsa' #=> "asddsa"
a #=> ["asd"]
```

Otherwise you could `Marshal.load(Marshal.dump(a))`:

```
deep_copy = Marshal.load(Marshal.dump(a))
deep_copy[0] << 'dsa' #=> "asddsa"
a #=> ["asd"]
```

Comment: I can't use gems for this. I'm still confused how marshal creates an duplicate of my array. Which is really all I want without the duplicate messing up my real array. I honestly don't even know why the duplicated array is acting like its the original in the first place.

Comment: First `Marshal.dump(a)` will pack a copy of `a` into a separate memory space (a bytes stream), effectively duplicating the entire data structure, but mangling the structure (as a byte stream). Second, `Marshal.load(~)` will unpack the entire data structure into a new variable `deep_copy`. In this way, you've duplicated the entire structure into a new variable that has no relation to the original. You have to be careful what you `Marshal` though. Some objects can't be treated correctly. (See: https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Marshal.html)

Comment: Also, when you say "duplicated array", you are actually using `clone` which according to the specification for `Object` states "Produces a shallow copy of obj—the instance variables of obj are copied, but not the objects they reference.". A "shallow" copy will give you another object that points to the same data. Manipulating that new object's data will modify the original. As others have stated, if you want to modify the old state of data and leave the old object state alone, `Marshal`ling or using `dup` will be the way to go.

Comment: @jackneedshelp what you really want is `Marshal.load(Marshal.dump(a))`. Read the docs to get less confused about it, as stated above.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that @puzzarray is an array containing (sub)arrays. If that is the case, then  this code

```
fakearray = []
@puzzarray.each_index do |row|
    fakearray << @puzzarray[row]
end
```

does indeed create a new array, but it contains the very same subarrays. The `<<` method , according to the docs, "pushes the given object on to the end of this array". The given object, not a copy.  This should be a remedy:

```
fakearray = []
@puzzarray.each_index do |row|
    fakearray << @puzzarray[row].dup
end
```

This is a shorter way to achieve the same:

```
fakearray = @puzzarray.map( &:dup )
```